# Was this miniature in "Requiem for Methuselah" ever used to portray the Enterprise in space?

Tags: props, star-trek, star-trek-the-original-series

In the *Star Trek: TOS* episode "Requiem for Methuselah", the title character shrinks the *Enterprise*.  You can see Kirk inspecting this miniature *Enterprise* on a table:

[image: mini Enterprise]

**Was this particular prop ever used to portray the *Enterprise* in space** (e.g. opening credits, orbiting a planet, or in battle)?

Related, but does not answer the question: [At how many different scales were starship Enterprise models produced?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/87912/65120)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the "three foot" model was used to film some special effects scenes of the *U. S. S. Enterprise* in outer space.

The "three-foot" model (actually 33 inches long instead of 36 inches) was completed and delivered on December 14, 1964, and was used to film all the special effects shots of the *Enterprise* in space in "The Cage", the first pilot film, up to December 24, 1964.

The eleven foot model of the Enterprise was delivered on December 29, 1964, and was used to film one special effects scene in "The Cage".

The "three foot" model was used to film the opening title sequence used in all episodes and for additional scenes in some episodes. Episodes which included scenes of the "three foot" model include: "Where No Man Has Gone Before", "Tomorrow is Yesterday", "By Any Other Name", where it was used for special effects in space scenes, and "Requiem for Methuselah" where it appeared on a table top as the original question said.

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Constitution_class_model_(original)[1](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Constitution_class_model_(original))

I asked for information on this subject at the Trek BBS site:

https://www.trekbbs.com/threads/tos-enterprise-filming-models.299515/#post-12927132[2](https://www.trekbbs.com/threads/tos-enterprise-filming-models.299515/#post-12927132)

This is supposed to be a list of all shots of the Enterprise, specifying which of the models were used:

http://www.trekplace.com/tosfxcatalog.html[3](http://www.trekplace.com/tosfxcatalog.html)

Comment: @DrSheldon  I expanded my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find any information on the *specific* prop (source: *These Are The Voyages: Vol 3* by Marc Cushman) but my understanding is that the shots of the *Enterprise* used in the opening credits, orbiting planets etc were done using a *much* larger model.

The prop in question appears too small for close up work on film and was likely made for the episode or pre-production reference purposes.

I did find a reference to a smaller pre-production model in *These Are The Voyages: Vol 1* by Marc Cushman) with the caption

> Roddenberry inspects a model of the U.S.S. Enterprise while on location at Desilu 40 Acres, before approving the making of the 11 foot 2 inch version.

[image]

### 11ft long model

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Your picture of the smaller model does a better job than mine at showing the scale of the model.  Would you say that this is the 3 foot model?

Comment: There does not seem to have been another model so it seems likely that the 3ft one was used in the episode.